# I want to add a statement. I tried parsing it, java parser exception is thrown. How to overcome it?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

I need to insert a statement as

```
int listSize = list.size();
```

So, I tried inserting that statement as

```
Statement sampleStatement = JavaParser.statement ("int listSize = list.size();");
```

Java parser exception is thrown.

​

P.s: I'm using java parser core 2.4.0

Comment: what exeption? shouldn't that be 'JavaParser.statement("int listSize = list.size();"); ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then elaborate: what exception do you get (stacktrace)? Where are you trying to insert that statement? Why are you using `JavaParser` in the first place? Assuming you mean `com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaParser` do you realize that it's commonly not advicable to directly use `com.sun.*` classes?

Comment: I am almost certain that the exception's message (whatever it might be) is trying to tell you something.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" Com.github.javaparser.ParseException: Encountered " "int" "int" at line 1,column1. was expecting one of: "False"... " new"... "null"... " super"... "this"... " true "... <LONG_LITERAL>... <INTEGER_LITERAL>...

Comment: That's because you provided a declaration, not a statement. Why keep the important part of your questIon secret?

Comment: While parsing the file, i have to insert the statement           int listSize=list.size();

Comment: While parsing the file, i have to insert the statement           int listSize=list.size(); How to make this as a statement? I'll be inserting the statement by declaration.getBody().getStmts().add(3,sampleStatement) .

Comment: Err, [use the correct API](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.2.5/com/github/javaparser/JavaParser.html#parseVariableDeclarationExpr-java.lang.String-)? Look it up? You can't turn something that isn't a statement into a statement. You're asking the wrong question.

Comment: Oh, then ,how insert this line int listSize=list.size(); in the file using java parser?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any statement(..) method within JavaParser class from com.github.javaparser::javaparser-core maven artifact

Shouldn't your code be something like

`Statement statement = JavaParser.parseStatement("listSize = list.size();");` ?

Comment: How to insert the type int in that statement?